# Update From with Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table using data from the first table. I'm trying to write something like this:

```
-- Create the temp tables
DROP TABLE #MyNewTable
CREATE TABLE #MyNewTable
    (
     UserId int IDENTITY(1, 1)
                NOT NULL,
     MarriedFlag bit NOT NULL
    )

DROP TABLE #MyOldTable
CREATE TABLE #MyOldTable
    (
     UserId int IDENTITY(1, 1)
                NOT NULL,
     Married nvarchar(50) NULL
    )

-- Insert test values
INSERT  INTO #MyOldTable
        ([Married])
VALUES  ('married'),
        ('married'),
        ('not married'),
        ('maybe married')
GO

-- First pass will do nothing as there is no data in #MyNewTable
UPDATE  #MyNewTable
SET     [MarriedFlag] = CASE I.[Married]
                          WHEN 'married' THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                        END
FROM    [#MyOldTable] AS I,
        [#MyOldTable] AS O
WHERE   I.[UserId] = O.[UserId]

-- Will insert 4 values into #MyNewTable
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [#MyNewTable] ON

INSERT  INTO #MyNewTable
        ([UserId],
         [MarriedFlag])
        SELECT  I.[UserId],
                CASE I.[Married]
                  WHEN 'married' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END
        FROM    [#MyOldTable] AS I
        WHERE   I.[UserId] NOT IN (SELECT   [UserId]
                                   FROM     [#MyNewTable])

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [#MyNewTable] OFF

SELECT  *
FROM    [#MyOldTable]

-- #MyOldTable Expected Output
UserId Married
1    married
2    married
3    not married
4    maybe married

SELECT  *
FROM    [#MyNewTable]

-- #MyNewTable Expected Output
UserId MarriedFlag
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
```

Something else to note is this is part of a trigger. The idea is when the old table is updated, the new values are cleaned up and if they are valid, it is inserted into the new table.

Comment: Telling us nothing more than "**no go**" means "**no go**" for answering this.

Comment: Are you getting error? What's marriedflag type is?

Comment: Your tables need a JOINing field, do they not? Are you sure you're not trying to do an INSERT?

Comment: Do you actually have 2 tables? Or these 2 names (`MyNewTable` and `MyOldTable`) are the same table?

Comment: Good catch @ypercube... at first glance I didn't realize the statement was calling what appears to be two tables with syntax that is meant for one.  I've updated my answer with a solution for either scenario.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was trying to write this off the top of my head while my wife was talking to me... :) I've updated the example to more clearly show what I was thinking. Andrew McLintock has the right idea. I am trying to change the married value to a bit value.

Comment: With my live tables, I wasn't getting any errors, just no output, so I didn't know what was going on. Now I am getting a type conversion error.

Comment: After updating my example to exactly what I have on my live server, it is no longer throwing the type conversion error and my example appears to be working, just not on my test server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think I know what you want to do. This creates a new table with an IsMarried flag instead of a descriptive value.

Let me know.

MAC

```
 SELECT OLD.id
    ,   OLD.[Name]
    ,   CASE (OLD.MaritalStatus )
            WHEN 'Married' then 1
        ELSE
            0   
        END AS IsMarried
INTO dbo.newTable
FROM dbo.oldTable AS OLD
```

TABLES:

OLD:

```
id  Name             MaritalStatus

1   Jack             Divorced  
2   Jill             Married   
3   James            Single    
4   Mark             Married
```

NEW:

```
id  Name           IsMarried

1   Jack           0
2   Jill           1
3   James          0
4   Mark           1
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the idea. I've updated my example above and tried to explain intent.

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining on anything with your inner/outer query.  If you return another field in your derived table (the id) and join on it you will be fine.  You will want to end your case statement before adding the extra id field.